# Syntax highlight - 404 not found?

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting, ajax

I recently wrote an answer with my firebug up and I noticed that there are requests to

https://stackoverflow.com/api/tags//syntax-highlight?_=1310389462423

which results in 404 Not found. Is that known and is that important to got it there?

EDIT: Just before submitting this form:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/api/tags//syntax-highlight?_=1310389594526

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Great catch; thanks.

Not a huge problem as far as functionality goes, but obviously causing quite a few unnecessary requests. Fixed in the next build.