# 404 page prompts incorrect suggestion

Tags: feature-request, 404-not-found

If I go to a [junk link](https://stackoverflow.com/thisisjunk) not necessarily looking for a question (say, [some specific error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95261/179372), [or another](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98114/179372) comes up), the message `"Try searching for similar questions"` is displayed.

Well, since I'm not searching for a question in the first place, is this really appropriate?

How about instead, simply: `"If you are looking for a question, try searching"`

Does this matter to anyone else?

---

**EDIT:**

Mind you, I'm not trying to say we should do any extra work to figure out what the user was trying to do, just present a more applicable/broad message to them.

Comment: Or do I need to add freehand circles to make my point?

Comment: Meh, how would you really tell whether what they typed in was an accidental misspelling or simply entering junk?  If we are going so far as to check whether the link might be to a relevant question, then adjust the 404 page to include links to related questions.

Comment: @saluce I'm not saying we do any extra thinking here, simply that we say '*IF* you are looking for a question, then try this' rather than just 'look for related questions!'

Comment: Ah...gotcha.  I was thinking you were proposing some heuristic to determine whether the user was searching a question or not and adjusting the text to match.